# Android - Show fragment on resume

Tags: android, android-fragments, lifecycle, resume, fragmentmanager

I currently have a navigation drawer, which has a few fragments (Home, Help, About) in my activity. On startup it opens up Home. The issue i'm having is that when i go to another fragment such as Help and then proceed to put the phone to sleep and subsequently turn on the phone back on it'll always return to Home instead of help.

I'm quite new to lifecycles but was hoping to get some feedback on how to resume from a different fragment.

EDIT: Provided relevant code
Update: Realised that this happens because i reinit the views on resume.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    initializeUI();
}


private void initializeUI() {


    fragAbout = new About();
    fragHelp = new Help();
    fragHome = new MyViewPager();


    // Adding fragments to activity
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.main_activity_fraglayout, fragHome);

    transaction.commit();

    ...


}

private void addDrawerItems() {

    ...

    DrawerItemAdapter drawerAdapter = new DrawerItemAdapter(this, R.layout.nav_list_row, drawerItems);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(drawerAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    ...
                    newFragOnClick(fragHome, "Home");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    ...
                    newFragOnClick(fragSettings, "Help");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    ...
                    newFragOnClick(fragAbout, "About");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
        }
    });
}

private void newFragOnClick(Fragment frag, String actionBarTitle){

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

    transaction.replace(R.id.main_activity_fraglayout, frag);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Comment: Please upload the full code of your activity

Comment: you can handle this navigation from hosted activity, replace the desired fragment in onResume() of hosted activity

Comment: @Farhan Yeah, that seems to work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use sharedpreferences to save the current tab position and in `onResume()` use it to move to the saved position.

Comment: Coincidentally, i do have a view pager (with tabs) somewhere else in my app and this is also relevant to what i need for something else. Thanks! However, the drawer is actually different to the view pager (with tabs).

Comment: Actually this logic can still be used. awesome. Thanks!